# how to change textbox data remotely by tcp socket in QT?

Tags: qt, sockets, qml

i would like to code a program by Qt tcp socket and QML together.
i am going to change a textbox variable that created by QML to the new data that get by remote client by tcp socket?
my snippet code is :

```
void Server::startRead()
{

   client->waitForReadyRead(3000);
   QString buf=  client->readAll();
   qDebug() << buf;
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
   engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

   QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
   QObject *qmlObject = rootObject->findChild<QObject*>("ttt");
   qDebug() << "before change"
   qDebug() << qmlObject->property("text");
   qmlObject->setProperty("text", "new data");
   qDebug() << "after change"
   qDebug() << qmlObject->property("text");

 }
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Window{
    width:400
    height:400
    visible:true

    Item {
      id: rootItem
      property string text
      Text {
        id: message
        text: rootItem.text
      }
    }

}
```

I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. Next examples demonstrate how to change qml element properties from cpp. If you need to change visibility just use bool properties instead of string that i used in examples.

**1. This is good solution i think.**

You could create qml adapter

```
class ServerQMLAdapter : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QString data READ data WRITE setData NOTIFY dataChanged)
public:
  explicit ServerQMLAdapter(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr) : QQuickItem(parent){}
  QString data() const {
    return mData;
  }
  void setData(const QString &data) {
    if(mData == data)
      return;
    mData = data;
    emit dataChanged();
  }
private slots:
/**
this slots called on data read
*/
  void onDataRead(const QString &data) {
    setData(data);
  }
private:
  QString mData = QString();
};
```

in application class you sould register your adapter

```
qmlRegisterType<ServerQMLAdapter>("ServerQMLAdapter", 1, 0, "ServerQMLAdapter");
```

After that you can use it in your qml file

```
import ServerQMLAdapter 1.0
Item {
  ServerQMLAdapter {
    id: myAdapter
  }
  Text {
    id: message
    text: myAdapter.data
  }
}
```

---

**2. You can change properties from cpp.**

Just like you do in your snippet

```
auto rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
rootObject->setProperty("text", "new data");
```

and add this propetry to your qml file

```
Item {
  id: rootItem
  property string text
  Text {
    id: message
    text: rootItem.text
  }
}
```

---

**3. Use invoked methods**

From you cpp file

```
auto rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(rootObject, "setText",
                              Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(data)));
```

and add function to your qml file

```
Item {
  id: rootItem
  function setText(data) {
    message.text = data;
  }
  Text {
    id: message
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for solution 1 - but in the setter you should check whether the *new value* is different from the *old value* before emitting the signal.

Comment: @derM yee i should fix that

Comment: thanks @Andrey Semenov i added qml file to my question can u look it please? my problem is that when client connect to my server and send new data to text box in server the window should appear and change old text data to new data. but Unfortunately the window appear and disappear automatically.

Comment: @rebwarkarimi move propery to top item. In your case it's window. Add id to it, and work with it just like in 2nd example. Don't try to find item from c++ it's not the best way to change propety.

Comment: Dear @AndreySemenov, i can find item because when checking it with qDebug function and print the result of property the property and textbox values changed  but the problem is the window appear and disappear automatically.

Comment: @rebwarkarimi then why not to use showMinimized() and showNormal() methods to control window visibility?